# Declare data value dynamicaly to chart js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

How Can add values from a variable to the chart data portion

```
var values= document.getElementById("chart1").value;

new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July','August','September','October','November','December'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Total Collection',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                data: values,
                fill: false,
            }]
        },
```

i want to displace the datas from variable Values to the data portion.please help me

Answer (score 0):

When creating the chart, you need to assign it to a constant that can be referenced later on when updating the values of its dataset.

```
const chart = new Chart(...
```

Then you could define an `input` element where the user would enter individual values separated by a space each. A `button` element would trigger the `addValues` function upon  a mouse click.

```
<input id="chart1"><button type="button" onClick="addValues()">
```

The `addValues` function would split the values from the `input` element and convert them to numbers to finally assign them to the `data` of the unique dataset. Then it needs to invoke `chart.update()`.

```
function addValues() {
  var values = document.getElementById("chart1").value;
  chart.data.datasets[0].data = values.split(/\s+/).map(v => Number(v));
  chart.update();
}
```

Please have a look at the following runnable code snippet to see how it works.

```js
function addValues() {
  var values = document.getElementById("chart1").value;
  chart.data.datasets[0].data = values.split(/\s+/).map(v => Number(v));
  chart.update();
}

const chart = new Chart('line-chart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Total Collection',
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      borderColor: 'blue',
      data: [],
      fill: false,
    }]
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
Values: <input id="chart1"><button type="button" onClick="addValues()">Add Values</button>
<canvas id="line-chart" height="80"></canvas>
```